# Train Keras model on party loaded data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to predict next character for a given string of length 100. The problem is when I'm generating training data my whole RAM (32 GB on Amazon AWS - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B077GCH38C?qid=1527197041958&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title) is being eaten and process is getting killed.

To build training data I iterate over list of articles (each have 500-1'000 chars). In each article I take first 100 chars as input and next char as output, then I move one char and repeat this till end of text. This approach produces a lot of training vectors, i.e. article that has 500 chars will produce about 400 test data and this is problem.

With 15k articles and sliding window 100 there will be millions of training data and my AWS machine (with 32 GB RAM t2.2xlarge - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B077GCH38C?qid=1527197041958&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title) is dying at about 79% - 35 million training data.

So my question is - is there a way in Keras to start learning model on, let's say 25% data, then load next 25% and do this until everything is consumed?

My pseudo code for learning:

```
with open(articles_path, 'rt', encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        article = line[0:-1]
        article_length = len(article)
        # here is the problematic code 
        for i in range(0, article_length - seq_length, 1):
            seq_in = article[i:i + seq_length]
            seq_out = article[i + seq_length]
            dataX.append([tokens[char] for char in seq_in])
            dataY.append(tokens[seq_out])

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(seq_length, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(len(tokens), activation=activation))
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)

model.fit(X, y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Note: when I was writing my own program I was using this tutorial https://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good time to switch to a generator, essentially you will spit out a batch a time instead of loading the entire dataset:

```
def data_gen(batch_size=32):
  """Yield single batch at a time."""
  dataX, dataY = list(), list()
  while True: # the generator yields forever
    # here is the problematic code 
    for i in range(0, article_length - seq_length, 1):
      for _ in range(batch_size):
        seq_in = article[i:i + seq_length]
        seq_out = article[i + seq_length]
        dataX.append([tokens[char] for char in seq_in])
        dataY.append(tokens[seq_out])
      yield np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)
      dataX, dataY = list(), list()
```

You can now train using `fit_generator` ([ref](https://keras.io/models/model/#methods)) which will take batches from your generator. So you only process `batch_size` number of samples and not the entire set. You might want to use NumPy arrays instead of Python lists.

For a more organised version, you can implement a [Sequence class](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) which encapsulates the data and acts as a generator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I needed! BTW why you are running this generator forever? Will ```model.fit_generator``` ends with this setting?

Comment: "An epoch finishes when `steps_per_epoch` batches have been seen by the model." So you specify how many batches there are. If you implement a `Sequence` the `len()` is used, the documentation covers all these worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach for data generation is interesting, but you don't have to generate **every** 100-byte sample out of your texts. Replace the problematic code with something like this:

```
    for i in range(0, article_length - seq_length, 1):
        if random.randint(1,10) not in [5, 6] : continue   # this will skip 80% of the samples
        seq_in = article[i:i + seq_length]
        seq_out = article[i + seq_length]
        dataX.append([tokens[char] for char in seq_in])
        dataY.append(tokens[seq_out])
```

Place `import random` somewhere around the beginning of the file. And once you put this into your code, only 1 out of 5 sequence will get into your training data, effectively reducing the size.

There's a way to make generation of the randomly sampled character strings more efficient, but it will require rewriting your code, and this approach just adds one extra line.

Comment: But in this way I'm not using all data I gathered. Isn't it a waste?

Comment: @MAGx2 you have a choice to use less amount of data and get the training running or have your program fail with "Insufficient memory" -- it's your choice =) There are different approaches, when you generate the data into the file and use that file as the input for the training, but for your educational project it's going to be an overkill. Start training with less data, there are stlll a lot of ways things can go wrong...

Comment: @MAGx2 NP, come back with more questions, i'm sure you're going to have a lot =)